# Sum of two palindromes to a different base equals a third palindrome to a different base

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, number-systems, palindrome

Is there a method to find when a palindrome in base $a$ plus a palindrome in base $b$ equals a palindrome in base $c$, with bases $a,b,c$ coprimes in pairs and each palindrome must have more than $2$ digits and can have a different number of terms?  Example: $101$ base $11=122$ and $101$ base $13=170$ to give $122+170=292$, a palindrome in base $10$. The example illustrates that it is possible and does not put restrictions  on the nature of each palindrome.  Perhaps the only way to find them is by trial and error?

Comment: Is there a particular reason for more than two digits? I assume more than one digit (two digits or more) is reasonable since one digit palindromes are palindromic in all bases greater than them. Why also exclude two digit palindromes? Just curious.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you mean finding solutions to $X_a+Y_b=Z_c$ where $X,Y,Z$ are palindromic in base $10$ and have more than two digits; and $a,b,c$ are coprime? What do you mean by "*each palindrome can have a different number of terms*" ?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the question asks if there is a way, other than trial and error, to find $X,Y,Z$ such that $X_a,Y_b,Z_c$ are all palindromes of at least three digits and $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,c)=\gcd(b,c)=1$

Comment: I can prove that there are no solutions of $101_a+101_b=101_c$ for $a,b,c$ are pairwise coprime integers by considering this equation mod 3 and concluding that $c$ must be a multiple of $3$, but then when I replace $c$ with $3k$ and consider it mod 3, I once again conclude that k must be a multiple of 3, ad infinitum.

Comment: The equation $101_a + 101_b = cdc_f$, i.e. $a^2 + b^2 + 2 = c (f^2 + 1) + d f$, will have infinitely many positive integer solutions for many values of $a,c,d$.  For example, with $a=2, c=5, d=0$ we get $101_2 + 101_{38} = 505_{17}$, $101_2 + 101_{682} = 505_{305}$, $101_2 + 101_{12238} = 505_{5473}$, etc.
it's the Pell equation $b^2 + 1 = 5 f^2$.

Comment: A novelty to consider is that 292 base prime 11=343=7 cubed, with 7 the prime just before 11.